# с++ использование единиц измерения для указания значений переменных

Tags: c++, c++11, переменные, c++14, преобразование-типов

**Подскажите, как современный стиль программирования на C++ рекомендует использовать единицы измерения при указания значений переменных?**

Мне совершенно не нравится использование `#define`, поскольку очень часто теряется смысловая нагрузка таких переменных, не видная привязка к конкретному классу (где это может быть использовано), да и просто не очень эстетично

```
#define _KBps 1024.0
```

Поэтому я использую статические константы. Например для класса, который работает с объектами в секунду и пользователь [кода] может указать определённые границы, я делаю так:

```
class CMyClass
{
public:
    static const double m_Ops;
    static const double m_KOps;
    static const double m_MOps;

// основная начинка класса
};

const double CMyClass::m_Ops = 1;
const double CMyClass::m_KOps = 1000.0;
const double CMyClass::m_MOps = 1000000.0;


CMyClass(2.0 * CMyClass::m_KOps, 1.34 * CMyClass::m_MOps);
```

Что уже (на мой скромный взгляд) более наглядно и удобно.

Но наверное С++1x  в этом отношении шагнули дальше и можно указывать

```
CMyClass(2.0KOps, 1.34MOps);
```

?

Так ли это (вроде что-то подобное видел)?
И вообще какой подход предпочтителен?

Comment: [boost.unit](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/doc/html/boost_units.html)

Comment: VVT, показалось (когда прочитал по твоей ссылке), что boost все таки несколько избыточен для моих задач, да и наверное есть есть стандартный аналог задачи лучше сделать на аналоге?

Comment: Я когда-то наткнулся на [это](http://rsdn.org/forum/src/1824757.flat) и сильно обрадовался, потом всячески пропагандировал такой подход. Жаль, до сих пор практически не применяется.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

См. п. 13.5.8 стандарта - литералы, определенные пользователем. Вот простейший пример:

```
long double operator ""_MOps(long double x) { return x*1e6; }

auto main() -> int
{
    cout << 2.0_MOps << endl;
}
```

Comment: Harry, да, наверное это то, что нужно. А есть ли какие-то общепринятые рекомендации к таким вещам? Например, можно ли сделать operator членом класса? Или обозначать лучше через _*** (посмотрел примеры, много где так ставят - понятно что на любителя, но все таки хочется общечеловеческий код :))

Comment: Честно говоря, я знаю, что такая возможность есть, но лично мне она кажется только запутывающей и сбивающей с толку, так что у меня к ней отношение предвзятое, а потому советовать что-то не могу...

Comment: Harry, это по поводу использования оператора в классе?

Comment: *"можно ли сделать operator членом класса?"* Такой - нет, нельзя. *"Или обозначать лучше через `_***`"* А есть какой-то другой способ?

Comment: Нет, вообще по поводу литеральных операторов. Насколько я знаю, в пределах класса они не объявляются.

Comment: imho их использование ограничено константами времени компиляции (т.е. вывести результат вычислений в файл и воспользоваться ими в другой программе будет нелегко)

Comment: А чего так main-то изуродовали? :)

Comment: @alexolut Все ждал, кто заметит :) На днях читал "C++ High Performance" Viktor Sehr и Björn Andrist - они так развлекаются. Ну, решил приколоться и я :)